# Gene expression programming [Java]: How to view the members of the population

Tags: java, evolutionary-algorithm, genetic-programming, watchmaker

I'm using a gene expression programming [library](http://www.gene-expression-programming.com/) demo to obtain alternative mathematical expressions. I downloaded all the class files for uncommons.watchmaker framework and created a new project that runs without jar files. [Java Project (full source code) is attached here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!Aj9lfQS8qKqwnWiXL_t6pVaPHu0y).

I have modified the [demo](https://github.com/automenta/gep4j/blob/master/src/org/gep4j/examples/TestSimpleExpression.java) a little bit to produce alternative mathematical expressions for a given number. For example let's say I want to get all the combinations of numbers between 2 - 11 which would multiply to give 12. I would get 6 * 2, 3 * 4, 3 * 2 * 2, 2 * 6, 4 * 3, 2 * 2 * 3. The main program is TestMainProg.java

I am interested in knowing **how to print the population of the final generation**.

Findings:

In the watchmaker API it says [evolvePopulation() in EvolutionEngine interface](http://watchmaker.uncommons.org/api/org/uncommons/watchmaker/framework/EvolutionEngine.html#evolvePopulation(int,%20int,%20org.uncommons.watchmaker.framework.TerminationCondition...)) can be used to get the final population data. However I am not sure how to invoke the method and print the data. Looking at the EvolutionEngine.java, EvaluatedCandidate.java and AbstractEvolutionEngine.java will be useful.

Below is the code I use:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.gep4j.GeneFactory;
import org.gep4j.INode;
import org.gep4j.INodeFactory;
import org.gep4j.IntegerConstantFactory;
import org.gep4j.KarvaEvaluator;
import org.gep4j.MutationOperator;
import org.gep4j.RecombinationOperator;
import org.gep4j.SimpleNodeFactory;
import org.gep4j.math.Multiply;
import org.uncommons.maths.random.MersenneTwisterRNG;
import org.uncommons.maths.random.Probability;
import org.uncommons.watchmaker.framework.EvolutionEngine;
import org.uncommons.watchmaker.framework.EvolutionObserver;
import org.uncommons.watchmaker.framework.EvolutionaryOperator;
import org.uncommons.watchmaker.framework.FitnessEvaluator;
import org.uncommons.watchmaker.framework.GenerationalEvolutionEngine;
import org.uncommons.watchmaker.framework.PopulationData;
import org.uncommons.watchmaker.framework.operators.EvolutionPipeline;
import org.uncommons.watchmaker.framework.selection.RouletteWheelSelection;
import org.uncommons.watchmaker.framework.termination.TargetFitness;

public class TestMainProg {
    final KarvaEvaluator karvaEvaluator = new KarvaEvaluator();
    public INode[] bestIndividual=null;

    public void go() {
        List<INodeFactory> factories = new ArrayList<INodeFactory>();

        // init the GeneFactory that will create the individuals

        //factories.add(new SimpleNodeFactory(new Add()));
        factories.add(new SimpleNodeFactory(new Multiply()));
        factories.add(new IntegerConstantFactory(2, 35)); //12,60,1 and the target number
        double num = 36.0;

        GeneFactory factory = new GeneFactory(factories, 20); //20 is the gene size

        List<EvolutionaryOperator<INode[]>> operators = new ArrayList<EvolutionaryOperator<INode[]>>();
        operators.add(new MutationOperator<INode[]>(factory, new Probability(0.01d)));
        operators.add(new RecombinationOperator<INode[]>(factory, new Probability(0.5d)));
        EvolutionaryOperator<INode[]> pipeline = new EvolutionPipeline<INode[]>(operators);

        FitnessEvaluator<INode[]> evaluator = new FitnessEvaluator<INode[]>() {
            @Override
            public double getFitness(INode[] candidate, List<? extends INode[]> population) {
                double result = (Double) karvaEvaluator.evaluate(candidate);
                double error = Math.abs(num - result);
                return error;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isNatural() {
                return false;
            }
        };

        EvolutionEngine<INode[]> engine = new GenerationalEvolutionEngine<INode[]>(factory, pipeline, evaluator,
                new RouletteWheelSelection(), new MersenneTwisterRNG());


        // add an EvolutionObserver so we can print out the status.         
        EvolutionObserver<INode[]> observer = new EvolutionObserver<INode[]>() {
            @Override
            public void populationUpdate(PopulationData<? extends INode[]> data) {
                bestIndividual = data.getBestCandidate();
                System.out.printf("Generation %d, PopulationSize = %d, error = %.1f, value = %.1f, %s\n", 
                                  data.getGenerationNumber(), data.getPopulationSize(),
                                  Math.abs(/*Math.PI*/ num - (Double)karvaEvaluator.evaluate(bestIndividual)), 
                                  (Double)karvaEvaluator.evaluate(bestIndividual), 
                                  karvaEvaluator.print(bestIndividual));    

            }
        };
        engine.addEvolutionObserver(observer);

        //to get the total population
        engine.evolvePopulation(100,10,new TargetFitness(0.0001, false));

    }

    public static final void main(String args[]) {
        new TestMainProg().go();        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce your code and your queston to the relevant parts. Most of the users here don't know the framework and therefore have no clue what you actually need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing all the correct candidates in the final population is simple:

```java
engine.evolvePopulation(100,10,new TargetFitness(0, false)).stream()
   .filter( e -> e.getFitness() == 0 ) // Find all survivors
   .map( e -> karvaEvaluator.print( e.getCandidate() ) ) // Convert to String
   .forEach( System.out::println ); // Print
```

Getting multiple two number combinations, however, is more tricky:

1. `GeneFactory` with a gene length of 5 or above *may* produce `A x B x C`, e.g. 2 x 2 x 9 = 36
2. Only one correct result is guaranteed in each evolution.

First point should be easy to fix.
For the second, we can run the evolution a few times and consolidate the results.
There is no guarantee you'll get all combinations, but the more you run the higher chance it will be.

> Optimisation tips: 
>   1. Number range should be as small as possible, i.e. 2 to (target/2).
>   2. Recombination is unnecessary since there is only multiplication. 
>   3. That leaves only (numeric) mutation, which can have a higher chance to occur.

My solution:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.gep4j.*;
import org.gep4j.math.Multiply;
import org.uncommons.maths.random.MersenneTwisterRNG;
import org.uncommons.maths.random.Probability;
import org.uncommons.watchmaker.framework.*;
import org.uncommons.watchmaker.framework.operators.EvolutionPipeline;
import org.uncommons.watchmaker.framework.selection.RouletteWheelSelection;
import org.uncommons.watchmaker.framework.termination.TargetFitness;

public class TestMainProg {
   private static final double NUM = 36.0;
   private static final int RUN = 50;

   public void go() {
      KarvaEvaluator karvaEvaluator = new KarvaEvaluator();

      GeneFactory factory = new GeneFactory( Arrays.asList(
         new SimpleNodeFactory(new Multiply()),
         new IntegerConstantFactory( 2, (int)(NUM/2) )
      ), 3 );

      EvolutionaryOperator<INode[]> pipeline = new EvolutionPipeline<>( Arrays.asList(
         new MutationOperator<>(factory, new Probability(0.5d))
      ) );

      FitnessEvaluator<INode[]> evaluator = new FitnessEvaluator<INode[]>() {
         @Override public double getFitness(INode[] candidate, List<? extends INode[]> population) {
            return Math.abs( NUM - (Double) karvaEvaluator.evaluate(candidate) );
         }
         @Override public boolean isNatural() {
            return false;
         }
      };

      EvolutionEngine<INode[]> engine = new GenerationalEvolutionEngine<>(factory, pipeline, evaluator,
            new RouletteWheelSelection(), new MersenneTwisterRNG());

      Set<String> results = new HashSet<>();
      for ( int i = 0 ; i < RUN ; i ++ ) {
         List<EvaluatedCandidate<INode[]>> finalPopulation =
            engine.evolvePopulation(100,10, new TargetFitness(0, false));
         // Add all survivors to result
         finalPopulation.stream().filter( e -> e.getFitness() == 0 )
            .map( e -> karvaEvaluator.print( e.getCandidate() ) )
            .forEach( results::add );
      }
      new TreeSet( results ).stream().forEach( System.out::println );
   }

   public static final void main(String args[]) {
      new TestMainProg().go();
   }
}
```